# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException When get value from TextField - Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am new to Javafx. I am learning Javafx by developing a simple application. I am trying go get value from TextField in javaFXML. I got `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

Javafx File.

```
public class Manoj extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="manoj.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="142.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="360.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="result" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="289.0" opacity="0.51" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="169.0" text="Result Of Addition">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Number#1 ">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="First Application" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Number#2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
              <Button fx:id="button" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="216.0" onAction="#addNumber" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Add Number">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cambria" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <TextField fx:id="textone" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="179.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="texttwo" layoutX="141.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="179.0" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </AnchorPane>
    </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label result;
    private TextField textone;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {

    }
    @FXML
    private void addNumber(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Clicked. !");
        String str = textone.getText();
        result.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

I am developing using netbeans with scene builder. When I run this project and click Add Number button, I got an exception.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at manoj.FXMLDocumentController.addNumber(FXMLDocumentController.java:33)
    ... 57 more
```

Please help me to get out of this exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the controller: `textone` doesn't have the `@FXML` annotation, so when you click the button, `addNumber` is called, but `textone` is null as it has not been instantiated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your comment [Jose Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda).

Just a simple careless mistake.
As [Jose Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) said, I added @FXML annotation for `textone` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
package net.remark.abs.invoice;

import java.util.Date;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import net.remark.abs_bos.Invoice;
import net.rojer.core.db.DataBase;
import net.rojer.javafx.tool.Tools;

public class FrameInvoice extends AnchorPane{

    @FXML 
    private TextField fldInvoiceNumber;

    @FXML
    private Label lblPrice;

    public FrameInvoice(){
        Tools.innitiateFxml(this);

    }

    @FXML
    private void  onSave (ActionEvent event){
        Invoice invo = new Invoice();
        invo.setDate(new Date());
        invo.setTotal(0);
        invo.setStat((true));
        DataBase.begin();
        DataBase.em().persist(invo);
        DataBase.commit();
        System.out.println("true");
    }   
}
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining the changes and how do this solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many posts regarding this error and many of them get failed.For me it was the same. try to make the fxml file again and let the IDE to create the controller and css. keep the default controller and css names as it is and attach newly created '.fxml' file to the code. For me It worked.copy the content from the scene builder ,but not by the xml code.