# Converting JavaFX application into Android APK - issues with HTML file loading Google Maps

Tags: android, javafx, apk, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to get an application written in JavaFX ported across to Android and for the most part I have been successful in my attempts. In that the application will run on Android after packaging an apk file using Netbeans IDE and Gradle.

But the problem I have is that the application will crash when trying to access a google map through JavaFX Webview component. What I am using is the following in JavaFX:

```
googleMapEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/googleLondonMap.html").toExternalForm());
```

And the html file is located under the **Resources** folder in the Gradle root folder.

When I test the application in Netbeans by right clicking on the Gradle root node and selecting Tasks --> Run --> Run. My application runs perfectly, including accessing the google map using the html file and JavaFX Webview.

The creation of the apk file is also successful in using  Tasks --> Android --> Android. But once I install the apk file on an android device and access the google map portion of my application it throws me out of the application
saying "Unfortunately  has stopped". Any clues on how to fix this?

Looking at the log file created using the adb command I saw the following output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6038): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038): Process: com.SundaeThePugApp, PID: 6038

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$336(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.access$lambda$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$4.get(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6038):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewE
```

Here is the build.gradle file and yes I am using the Verdana font. But the font is coming through OK from what I can see on my android device.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.SundaeThePugApp.SundaeThePugFX'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:2.1.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.1.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Zermatt/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/'
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Found the cause for the Fatal Exception. It appears Android does not like the following block of code:

```
URL resource= getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Music/ThemeMusic.mp3");
        themeSong = new MediaPlayer(new Media(resource.toString()));
        themeSong.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable()
        {   public void run()
            {   themeSong.seek(Duration.ZERO);
            }
        });
        themeSong.play();
```

And this block of code comes up with error message in Android:

```
googleMapEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/googleLondonMap.html").toExternalForm());
```

Webpage not available:
The webpage at jar:file:/data/app/com.SundaeThePugApp - 1/base .apk!/googleLondonMap.html
could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

so what can I do now to rectify this?

**EDIT AGAIN**

Experimenting with Jose solution and building upon it, I found a way to get the JavaScript in the Html working although it ain't pretty. Essentially the code he supplied I put into a method (called createAndroidURLScheme) and returned a string. Here is the code and yes it works fine in JavaFX, but not in Androids webview again:

```
String url = createAndroidURLScheme("/googleTestMap.html");
//System.out.println(url);
googleMapEngine.loadContent(url, "text/html");
googleMapEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                googleMapEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>()
                {   public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, final State oldState, final State newState)
                    {   if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED)
                        {   googleMapEngine.executeScript(
                                "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.438722, 24.745278);" +
                                "var myOptions = {" + 
                                "zoom: 15," +
                                "center: latlng," +
                                "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP," +
                                "mapTypeControl: false," +
                                "navigationControl: false," +
                                "streetViewControl: false," +
                                "backgroundColor: '#666970'," +
                                "disableDefaultUI: true" +
                                "};" +
                                "" +
                                "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Now through logcat I get this new Android Fatal Exception:

```
    I/System.out(  809): [JVDBG] Error firing event

W/System.err(  809): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView._fireLoadEvent(InternalWebView.java:347)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView.fireLoadEvent(InternalWebView.java:140)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView.access$400(InternalWebView.java:43)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView$MyJavaScriptInterface.processHTML(InternalWebView.java:363)

W/System.err(  809):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

W/System.err(  809): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

W/System.err(  809):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

W/System.err(  809):    ... 11 more

W/System.err(  809):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

W/System.err(  809):        ... 12 more

W/System.err(  809):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): Process: com.SundaeThePugApp, PID: 809

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:153)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:860)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.SundaeThePugApp.SundaeThePugController$1.changed(SundaeThePugController.java:202)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.SundaeThePugApp.SundaeThePugController$1.changed(SundaeThePugController.java:200)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1134)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1000(WebEngine.java:1016)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1003)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:251)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView$1.run(NativeWebView.java:100)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$155(PlatformImpl.java:295)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$156(PlatformImpl.java:294)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.SundaeThePugApp

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.SundaeThePugApp

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.sec.android.app.launcher
```

What can I do now to alleviate this and keep Androids Webview happy?

Comment: With your device connected, can you run on command line `adb logcat -v threadtime`, and look for an exception? Post the relevant part

Comment: Hi Jose, Thank you for trying to help me. I found the adb.exe file under: c:\Users\Zermatt\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, so I connected my android device via usb cable to the computer then I ran the command you suggested in the command prompt screen at the above folder address location. When I ran the command all I got is: daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037, next line it said daemon started successfully, next line - waiting for device - now after 15 minutes nothing more seems to be happening. Should it take a long time? Sorry not familiar with this tool!

Comment: Sorry Jose, New to this stuff after reading further. I realised I had to turn developer options on and activate usb debugging. I have now created a txt file using the following command: adb logcat -d > logcat.txt. As the verbose was so long I could not see all of it via the command prompt window.

Comment: Now that we have a trace of the exception, could you share the full output (via gist or pastebin) ?

Comment: I've looked through by doing a word search on the text file and there is no line saying "Caused By" to give an indication for the reason why I receive an InvocationTargetException. This exception never occurs at any other stage of testing?

Comment: I can't say without having a look at it

Comment: Trying to setup up a pastebin account have been unable to activate it yet.

Comment: Jose, Under the account of Zermatt on Pastebin you will find public pastes from Logcat 1 to 5 covering the trace of exceptions that are available for your perusal.

Comment: I can't get in, can you create a public link?

Comment: I've double checked and it says that all five pastes are public pastes and everybody can see these pastes and I've already had between 37 and 50 hits according to pastebin. So I assume other people can see this?

Comment: Ok, got it. Have you seen this exception in log1 `java.lang.Exception: Font name not found.`? Could you post here your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: You can update the plugin to 1.0.8. Could you run without the font? Otherwise the solution to avoid the exception will be adding the ttf to resources and loading it.

Comment: Any thoughts Jose on the what could be causing the Fatal Exception? I tried putting a try / catch for a invocationtargetexception in my code where the Fatal Exception is occurring, but Netbeans says that this exception is never thrown and doesn't like me trying to put it there. I added the Verdana font to my resources file and recreated the apk, but the java.lang,Exception is still thrown when I created a new logcat file. This fatal exception is not giving me any hint at what could be causing the problem leaving me feeling stumped!

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420683/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-when-get-value-from-textfield-java), maybe you are missing an `@FXML` annotation?. If you have updated to 1.0.8, and loaded the font, could you update the logcat file (using `logcat -v threadtime`)?

Comment: Nope, that's not my problem in this scenario, if it was I would see it when compiling the project in Netbeans before moving everything to my gradle project. At least in that occurrence the invocationtargetexception listed a caused by statement in the log. Mine does not show that in the logcat which leaves me flying blind as to what the problem is?

Comment: I'm blind as well, since I can't see the project. Can  you share the minimum part of it so I can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi Jose, Can you provide any clarity on how to avoid Android saying net :: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME as this is the most important part I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the latest information provided, you have two known issues:

**Media**

If you have a look at [this](http://gluonhq.com/knowledge-base/exception-trying-run-audioclip-media-mobile/), Media is not supported yet, so you'll need to take it out.

**Url scheme error**

If you have a look at the `URL` showed by the error message, `jar:file:/data/.../base.apk!/googleLondonMap.html`, the `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` means that `jar:file` is not a known protocol on Android.

The reason for this is that loading an html file from a jar file is not supported by the android SDK.

Anyhow, the resource is accessible, so as a workaround, you could just load the html file into a string and provide that to the `WebEngine` using the method `loadContent` instead.

Something like this should work:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/googleLondonMap.html")));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
engine.loadContent(writer.toString());
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help Jose. I liked your explanation above on loading an html file from a jar file is not supported by the Android SDK. I wasn't aware of this limitation previously. I don't know whether my porting can proceed now because of this limitation? Although it got rid of the url scheme error. I feel I have inched slightly closer, but what I got was a blank white screen now where the map should have been and its positioning does not adhere to the GUI designed in Scene Builder. As my first JavaFX to Android port I still have learnt alot from this process.

Comment: Try to load a more simpler html page, checking that it gets fully loaded (minimum content possible). You can print to the console (`System.out.println()`) and then check with `adb logcat` that you get there. If that works, start adding content, and find out about possible issues. Also check that it works first on Desktop.

Comment: The approach doesn't work when I try to run it on the desktop using Netbeans - Task --> Run --> Run. The application comes up but their is no google maps being displayed at all. All I get is a grey out background with no errors. Until I try to perform one of the other functions in the html file and I get this: Caused by: netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: If it doesn't work on Desktop, it won't work on mobile. So try to fix it first on desktop, and check why it doesn't load the html content.

Comment: OK Jose, I think the problem I have with this approach is that yes it will pick up what is written between the <body></body> tags of the html document e.g. Hello World. However when calling a javascript onload function it doesn't work using engine.loadContent(writer.toString()). Using a System.out.println() I can see the entire contents of the file is there which is reassuring. My html documents are very similar to those in the FXExperience website for the maps example: [link](http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/)

Comment: Hi Jose, I've posted my findings on another question that I wrote on Stack Overflow. This is the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612445/how-compatible-is-javafx-webview-with-androids-webview/36685130#36685130)[link]. I hope you don't mind if I ask if you can forward it on to the relevant people to have a look at with your contacts.