# How compatible is JavaFX Webview with Android's Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, javafx, webview, apk

I've been trying to port a JavaFX project using Netbeans and Gradle into an Android APK file format and for the most part it works well! The issue I'm having is with the WebView component of Android in particular? I can get it to show a static webpage in Android Webview without my app falling over with a FATAL EXCEPTION. But if I create a dynamic webpage in JavaFX Webview using JavaScript, Androids Webview doesn't appear to cope at all?

Eventhough in JavaFX I set enable JavaScript to true:

```
googleMapEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

As I'm aware that in Android Webview - JavaScript is switched off by default.
I cannot get it to work in Android. In addition, does Android Webview know how to resolve the JavaFX command?

```
googleMapEngine.executeScript(String);
```

Cause if I try this:

```
googleMapEngine.executeScript(
      "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.438722, 24.745278);" +
      "var myOptions = {" + 
           "zoom: 15," +
           "center: latlng," +
           "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP," +
           "mapTypeControl: false," +
           "navigationControl: false," +
           "streetViewControl: false," +
           "backgroundColor: '#666970'," +
           "disableDefaultUI: true" +
      "};" +
      "" +
      "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);");
```

I end up with error in logcat:

```
    I/System.out(  809): [JVDBG] Error firing event

W/System.err(  809): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView._fireLoadEvent(InternalWebView.java:347)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView.fireLoadEvent(InternalWebView.java:140)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView.access$400(InternalWebView.java:43)

W/System.err(  809):    at com.oracle.dalvik.InternalWebView$MyJavaScriptInterface.processHTML(InternalWebView.java:363)

W/System.err(  809):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

W/System.err(  809):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

W/System.err(  809): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

W/System.err(  809):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)

W/System.err(  809):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)

W/System.err(  809):    ... 11 more

W/System.err(  809):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)

W/System.err(  809):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

W/System.err(  809):        ... 12 more

W/System.err(  809):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): Process: com.SundaeThePugApp, PID: 809

E/AndroidRuntime(  809): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:153)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:860)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.SundaeThePugApp.SundaeThePugController$1.changed(SundaeThePugController.java:202)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.SundaeThePugApp.SundaeThePugController$1.changed(SundaeThePugController.java:200)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1023)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1134)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1000(WebEngine.java:1016)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1003)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:251)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView$1.run(NativeWebView.java:100)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$155(PlatformImpl.java:295)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$156(PlatformImpl.java:294)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)

E/AndroidRuntime(  809):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.SundaeThePugApp

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.SundaeThePugApp

V/ApplicationPolicy( 3468): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.sec.android.app.launcher
```

All feedback will be most welcomed :)

Comment: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.NativeWebView

this means you do not have this class located in your Project, which means you need to import the jar associated with it.  Hope this helps get you on the right track, as I'm not sure what the rest of your issues are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after much trial and errors I have come to the conclusion that JavaFXPorts on the whole is damn good, but their are some caveats:

1) Media and Audio capabilities are not possible with your app at present as it throws a **Fatal Exception**.

2) Webview is limited to rendering **non** javascript websites.

I'll explain, if I use:

```
googleMapEngine.load("http://fxexperience.com/");
```

**Perfect, everything works fine and the page is rendered properly.**

But if I do this:

```
googleMapEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
googleMapEngine.load("https://www.openstreetmap.org/");
```

I get **NO** map and all I can see in my app is the open street map logo and a menu button, otherwise the rest of the webview is white! Also enabling JavaScript in JavaFX seems to have **no effect** on Androids webview leaving **Androids default setting** to false!

What about if I do the most simplest Google Map url possible:

```
googleMapEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
googleMapEngine.load("https://www.google.com/maps/");
```

I get **nothing** but a white screen! Also enabling JavaScript in JavaFX seems to have **no effect** on Androids webview leaving **Androids default setting** to false!

if I do a local html file with its path correctly made:

```
googleMapEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
googleMapEngine.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("googleLondonMap.html").toExternalForm());
```

I receive a **net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME** in the Android webview.

Finally, as Androids Webview default javascript setting is set to false. This means if ever you try to use JavaFX statement:

```
googleMapEngine.executeScript(foo());
```

It will cause a **FATAL EXCEPTION** in your android app. It would be sweet if Johan Vos and Co can overcome these Android WebView porting issues with future updates to their excellent work on JavaFXPorts!

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We have filed an issue to find out why `executeScript()` is failing on Android. In the meantime you can have a look at this [post](http://gluonhq.com/announcing-gluon-maps/) as an alternative that wouldn't require WebView nor JavaScript.

Comment: Thank's Jose for your assistance on the matter and the link you posted. I will have a look into this. Also I think an issue should be filed as to why `webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` is not working or having the desired effect on Androids webview.